# Hidden button in print dialog still showing in other PC's

Tags: css

I have 2 buttons on my print page: `Print` and `Export`.
I have written CSS for them to be hidden when printing, but the `Export` button is still showing on my friend's PC. On my computer, the buttons are hidden, as they should be.

This is the code I use to hide the buttons:

```css
@media print {
  #print {
    display: none;
  }
  
@media print {
  #export {
    display: none;
  }
```

just for information.. i have try to update the browser in that PC to try when my code doesn't support at the browser.

Comment: on which browser(s) and version(s) it isn't working?

Comment: You have some missing closing brackets in your code.

Comment: Add both CSS rules in one `@media` query and make sure all brackets are closed.

Comment: @SebastianBrosch google crome..
i have try to update it and it stil  same. in my friend PC

Comment: @beerwin the problem is on my PC's my hide function in running well and the button has been hidden there

Answer (score 1):

it looks like the wrong syntax. Did you try something like this:

```
@media print {
     #print {
        display: none;
     }
     #export {
         display: none;
     }
 }
```

if this does not help. try to right-click on the button and choose inspect element option. There you have all css applied to the button. Probably some other css rule is applied with stronger selector (is higher in the list)

Comment: the problem is not from the code bro.
my code running well at the other PC. just only two PC's still displaying that button.
i have try to update the browser and still has same problem. btw i use Chrome for open my page

Comment: it must be cache then: https://superuser.com/questions/220179/how-can-i-do-a-cache-refresh-in-google-chrome/512833#512833

Answer (score 0):

Club all the style declarations for each ID under the `@media print` media query like so:

```
@media print {
    #print, #export {
        display: none;
    }
}
```